# Codename One media file I/O exception on Arch Linux

Tags: codenameone, media-player

I am developing an Android application that I have almost finished on Ubuntu and that is gaining the final touch on Arch Linux.

I have reinstalled Java and Eclipse, and the project is running without a problem, except that the media files cannot be executed, even if the classes all the same and the media files in the same location.

The code is exactly the same, only the platform has changed. I have tried with both open-jdk-8 and open-jdk-11.

This is the code from a testing project:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    Button buttonSound = new Button("Play");
    buttonSound.addActionListener(l -> {
        InputStream inputStream = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/children-hooray.wav");
        try {
            Media media = MediaManager.createMedia(inputStream, "audio/wav");
            media.play();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    hi.add(buttonSound);
    hi.show();
```

[image]

Upon loading the console output is:

```
Adding CEF to classpath
Found theme.css file.  Watching for changes...
CSS> Retina Scale: 1.0
CSS> Using stateful mode. Use -help flag to see options for new stateless mode.
CSS> Looks like this CSS file needs CEF on classpath... adding it now, and retrying...
CSS> Adding CEF to classpath
Retina Scale: 1.0
CSS> Retina Scale: 1.0
CSS> Using stateful mode. Use -help flag to see options for new stateless mode.
CSS> Updating merge file /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test_En/css/theme.css.merged
CSS> Starting watch thread to watch [/home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test_En/css/theme.css]
CSS> Compiling /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test_En/css/theme.css.merged to /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test_En/src/theme.res
CSS> File has not changed since last compile.
CSS> CSS file successfully compiled.  /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/A1_Test_En/src/theme.res
```

and the Stack Trace is this :

```
    Adding CEF to classpath
    Retina Scale: 1.0
    java.io.IOException
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createMedia(JavaSEPort.java:8506)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.createMedia(Display.java:3597)
    at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:308)
    at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:226)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Main.lambda$1(Main.java:65)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:687)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:728)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:835)
    at com.codename1.ui.LeadUtil.pointerReleased(LeadUtil.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3817)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:4710)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2359)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1244)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1162)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: If you look within the jar is the file packaged there correctly?

Comment: I have generated a new jar and the problem continues, unfortunately ... please see my updated query

Comment: I have just generated a testing project that has the same issue. The question has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Is CEF used/loaded in the new machine? Do you see other printouts besides the exception?

Comment: I found and installed this package here : https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/cef-minimal/ but the same error still occurs. And there are no other console outputs besides the ones I have added above. One thing that I don't know if it is relevant is that I have to explicitly remove the launch after closing the simulator. And in the problems section is the following observation : Unknown referenced nature: codenameone.codenameonenature.

Comment: When I refresh the libraries, I get this:  Copying 2 files to /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/TestSound/build/tmp
       [javac] /home/rainer/eclipse-workspace/TestSound/build.xml:106: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
       [javac]

Comment: And after installing CEF, the prints upon loading: Adding CEF to classpath .... the the error message above, after pressing the button

Comment: It will only work with our CEF but if I remember arch Linux is a bit of a special case and doesn't play nicely with everything... Here are our instructions for CEF: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/big-changes-jcef.html

Comment: I just followed the installation instructions on that site I discovered that the directory is already there with the contents identical to those of the downloaded CEF zip file. So, it seems not to be due the missing CEF.

Comment: What's printed in the console other than that? I'm guessing the CEF failed to load properly under arch linux. In which case you might need to force the old JavaFX pipeline by switching to a VM that supports FX (e.g. ZuluFX 11) and removing the CEF directory.

Comment: I have added a new complete stack trace above. It does say : Adding CEF to classpath  ..... I have tried with ZuluFX (azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?package=jdk), but it does not work, either .. and Netbeans shows the same error

Comment: When you try with zulu you need to remove the CEF directory to force the FX pipeline

Comment: Changing to ZuluFx finally worked. Thanks for your patience ...

Comment: That stack trace looks incomplete.  Does it have a "Caused By..." stack trace following it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no stack trace beyond the one I have posted above. I have double checked. The launch seems to stop at one point, though, because I have to remove it manually after closing the simulator. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

With the aid from CN1, I finally managed to get ZuluFx installed and the media files working on Arch Linux. I post this in case my approach might be helpful to others:

- Download ZuluFx form [here](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-11-lts&os=linux&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx) (I have chosen to install Java version  11, but there are many more);
- Extract it into this directory: /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.45.27-ca-fx-jdk11.0.10-linux_x64;
- Delete/ rename the directory /home/user/.codenameone/cef;
- Change the Java version for the project following the guide [here](https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-change-java-version): Open Eclipse Window - Preferences -> Installed JRE -> Add -> Standard VM

[This](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/big-changes-jcef.html) CN1-article is also a helpful read.

Comment: This issue should be solved by the maven project support. So a better workaround might be a maven migration