# Codename One CSS box shadow compiling error (on Arch Linux)

Tags: css, codenameone

I am finalizing an Android application on Arch Linux that I started on Ubuntu. The IDE is Eclipse.

When I run the code on Arch, I get a `MissingNativeBrowserException`.

Narrowing the problem down, I found that the responsible line of code is related to the box-shadow in the theme.css file:

```
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2pt 1pt rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
```

Due to prior issues, I am using Java ZuluFx, instead of CEF, but I don't know if this related to the issue.

Below is the full stack-trace :

```
CSS> com.codename1.designer.css.MissingNativeBrowserException
CSS>    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI$3.getWebView(CN1CSSCLI.java:861)
CSS>    at com.codename1.designer.css.CSSTheme.createImageBorders(CSSTheme.java:2562)
CSS>    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.compile(CN1CSSCLI.java:916)
CSS>    at com.codename1.designer.css.CN1CSSCLI.main(CN1CSSCLI.java:780)
CSS>    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp._main(ResourceEditorApp.java:568)
CSS>    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp.main(ResourceEditorApp.java:258)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
CSS>    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
CSS>    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.CN1Bootstrap.run(CN1Bootstrap.java:218)
CSS>    at com.codename1.impl.javase.CN1Bootstrap.run(CN1Bootstrap.java:96)
CSS>    at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorApp.main(ResourceEditorApp.java:265)
```

Answer (score 1):

Our CEF support doesn't seem to work on Arch Linux at this time. See this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3374

That's a problem since the CEF support is integral to newer functionality in Codename One and is now a part of the designer tool as well. I'm not sure when/if we'll be able to address this since I'm not sure I know where to begin.

If you wish to continue using the [workaround of removing CEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66195644/codename-one-media-file-i-o-exception-on-arch-linux) there will be a couple of problems:

- You will need to do it every week as we push out CEF updates
- You will need to use an older version of the designer that doesn't try to use CEF either

For your convenience I placed an old version of designer (pre-cef change) here: https://www.codenameone.com/files/updates/old/designer_1.jar

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the honest answer and the links. I don't use the designer, though. But I will keep checking for the CEF updates on a regular basis.