# can't use create CEF browser from codename one

Tags: java, linux, codenameone, archlinux

My app is failing to run the BrowserComponent everytime I try to call it inside codename one. It gives me an error of failure to create CEF browser. Everything beside that is running just fine. I uninstalled and installed CEF as instructed in this link [Codename One CEF Support](https://github.com/shannah/codenameone-cef/blob/master/README.adoc#linux-unsatisfied-link)
I tried to fix my problem as I found it inside Known Issues from the previous link

I did as instructed and tried to fix the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

here is the output of my terminal after I did so  :

```
[kagha@archbios ~]$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java
[kagha@archbios ~]$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk
[kagha@archbios ~]$ echo  $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/lib/amd64
[kagha@archbios ~]$ find /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/ | grep "libawt.so"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
```

but the problem is still there
I am using the OS Arch Linux with Kernel version 5.10.32-1-lts and Apache netbeans 12.1 as an IDE

The code I am trying to run

```
Form hi = new Form("Browser", new BorderLayout());
BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
browser.setURL("https://www.codenameone.com/");
hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);*/
```

Here is the full error in the console:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,282 - Attempting to create browser component
[AWT-EventQueue-0] 0:0:0,284 - Attempting to create browser component
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/kagha/.codenameone/cef/lib/linux64/libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[EDT] 0:0:0,326 - Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - /home/kagha/.codenameone/cef/lib/linux64/libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[EDT] 0:0:0,327 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Failed to create CEF browser
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1830)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.cef.CefApp.startup(CefApp.java:536)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:207)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:139)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:121)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create CEF browser
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:133)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:98)
    at com.codename1.ui.BrowserComponent$9.run(BrowserComponent.java:557)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1338)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1280)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1162)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/kagha/.codenameone/cef/lib/linux64/libjcef.so: libjawt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1830)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap$1.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:24)
    at org.cef.SystemBootstrap.loadLibrary(SystemBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.cef.CefApp.startup(CefApp.java:536)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:207)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:199)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.CEFBrowserComponent.create(CEFBrowserComponent.java:196)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort.createCEFBrowserComponent(JavaCEFSEPort.java:139)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.cef.JavaCEFSEPort$2.run(JavaCEFSEPort.java:121)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

I will appreciate any help and provide more information if needed, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new [Maven support](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-maven.html). This should fix issue as the Maven plugin will automatically add the needed entries to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

You can download a base template from https://start.codenameone.com and just paste your code there.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302275/codename-one-css-box-shadow-compiling-error-on-arch-linux) , I checked your other answer and you suggested deleting the CEF folder , so I did rm -Rf ~/.codenameone/cef , and things started to work , I guess I'll do that for now as I didin't encounter any problem , if anything goes wrong I'll use the Maven support . Thanks for your answer.